# Laravel 8 - Factories & Foreign Keys

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-factory

I haven't been able to locate how to manage foreign keys when creating Factories and Seeders.

I have a `users` table and a `blog_posts` table. The `blog_posts` table has a foreign key `user_id` that references `users.id`. I would like to seed my database with users and blog posts.

I have seen how to create a new user for each seeded blog post with the following:

```
/**
 * Define the BlogPost model's default state.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function definition()
{
    return [
        'user_id' => User::factory(),
        'created_at' => now(),
        'updated_at' => now(),
        'title' => $this->faker->words(5, true),
        'body' => $this->faker->paragraphs(6, true)
    ];
}
```

...but I would like to reference existing users since I am performing the database seed like so:

```
/**
 * Seed the application's database.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{
    $this->call([
        UsersTableSeeder::class, 
        BlogPostsTableSeeder::class
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We can retrieve a random existing `User` and assign it in the `BlogPost` `Factory` as follows:

```
/**
 * Define the BlogPost model's default state.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function definition()
{
    return [
        'user_id' => User::inRandomOrder()->first()->id,
        'created_at' => now(),
        'updated_at' => now(),
        'title' => $this->faker->words(5, true),
        'body' => $this->faker->paragraphs(6, true)
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your User model has a `hasMany` relationship called `blogPosts`, you could do the following:

```
User::factory()
    ->hasBlogPosts(6)
    ->create();
```

This would create your User and 6 associated BlogPosts.

Comment: This is definitely an option but it would be more ideal if the blog post factory created the blog post and just looked to see what users exist from the user factory.

Comment: In which case the answer by [Stefano](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65819881/281278) is probably what you’re after.